# Trigger action from UIButton click on custom XIB

Tags: ios, swift, xib

I am building a quote app using [TGLParallaxCarousel](https://github.com/taglia3/TGLParallaxCarousel/) library in my project. I try to custom the `CustomView` of `TGLParallaxCarouselItem` by adding two `UIButton`s (favButton and shareButton) on it.

[screenshot to the quote cards (CustomView) I create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olJmR.png)

I am able to change the UIButton view based on its state--whether the current quote is faved or not, by doing this:

```
convenience init(frame: CGRect, number: Int) {
   self.init(frame: frame)
   currentQuote = quoteData[number]
   favButton.tag = number
   currentQuote.faved == true ? favButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "fav-on"), for: .normal) : favButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "fav-off"), for: .normal)    
}
```

However I need to be able to turn the fav on and off by clicking the favButton. I tried to connect the favButton directly as an `IBAction` to the `XIB` file, tried to `addAction` to function, but I still can't access the favButton click state.

Please help. What should I do?

**UPDATE**

I've tried `addTarget` on favButton. It's not working. My tap is detected as tap on CustomView rather than specifically on favButton.

Here's the `detectTap` function that fired when I tap anywhere on the CustomView (including on the favButton). This function is within the TGLParallaxCarousel.swift

```
func detectTap(_ recognizer:UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    let targetPoint: CGPoint = recognizer.location(in: recognizer.view)
    currentTargetLayer = mainView.layer.hitTest(targetPoint)!

    guard let targetItem = findItemOnScreen() else { return }

    let firstItemOffset = (items.first?.xDisp ?? 0) - targetItem.xDisp
    let tappedIndex = -Int(round(firstItemOffset / xDisplacement))
    self.delegate?.carouselView(self, didSelectItemAtIndex: tappedIndex)

    if targetItem.xDisp == 0 {
        self.delegate?.carouselView(self, didSelectItemAtIndex: tappedIndex)
    }
    else {
        selectedIndex = tappedIndex
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use `addTarget`?

```
convenience init(frame: CGRect, number: Int) {
    self.init(frame: frame)
    currentQuote = quoteData[number]
    favButton.tag = number
    currentQuote.faved == true ? favButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "fav-on"), for: .normal) : favButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "fav-off"), for: .normal) 

    favButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(toggle), for: .touchUpInside)   
}

@objc fileprivate func toggle() {
    currentQuote.faved = !currentQuote.faved
    currentQuote.faved == true ? favButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "fav-on"), for: .normal) : favButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "fav-off"), for: .normal)
}
```

Comment: I've tried addTarget, not working. I must inform that this might be due to the behavior of the TGLParallaxCarousel. My tap is detected as a tap on the CustomView rather than specifically on the favButton.